# Show filtered results in Listbox based on Textbox values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file automated with VBA in Excel. In this file, I added a Userform and functions. I want to add a function that if I write something or insert a letter or word in the TextBox of (Customer Name) it will automatically display the results in the ListBox or it will dropdown the results in the TextBox (if possible). Please see photo below for my UserForm.

This is the scripts I recently used below:

```
Private Sub TextBox13_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.TextBox13.Text = StrConv(Me.TextBox13.Text, vbProperCase)
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    For i = 4 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("D:D", "p:p"))
        For x = 4 To 9
            a = Len(Me.TextBox13.Text)
            If Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, x).Value, a) = Me.TextBox13.Text And Me.TextBox13.Text <> "" Then
                Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 9).Value
                For c = 4 To 9
                    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, c) = Sheet1.Cells(i, c + 1).Value
                Next c
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox13.SetFocus
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = Sheet1
    TextBox13.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox13_Change()
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long, i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim SearchString As String
    
    If Len(Trim(TextBox13.Text)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    SearchString = TextBox13.Text
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in col D
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the rows in col D
        For rw = 4 To lRow
            '~~> Loop trough columns D to I
            For col = 4 To 9
                '~~> Match using LIKE
                If .Cells(rw, col).Value Like SearchString & "*" Then
                    ListBox1.AddItem .Cells(rw, 9).Value
                    For i = 4 To 9 '<~~ Sure about this?????
                        ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, i) = .Cells(rw, i + 1).Value
                    Next i
                End If
            Next col
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

And if my understanding is correct, the names are in `Col D` then you may be trying the below

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = Sheet1
    TextBox13.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox13_Change()
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim SearchString As String
    
    If Len(Trim(TextBox13.Text)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    SearchString = TextBox13.Text
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in col D
        lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Loop through the rows in col D
        For rw = 4 To lRow
            '~~> Match using LIKE
            If .Cells(rw, 4).Value Like SearchString & "*" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem .Cells(rw, 4).Value
                '~~> Loop trough columns E to I
                For col = 5 To 9
                    ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, col - 4) = .Cells(rw, col).Value
                Next col
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There is something wrong in the script lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: "That something" is wrong because you did not copy the code as I posted it... **1.** Did you declare `Dim ws As Worksheet` at the top? **2.** Did you put `Set ws = Sheet1` in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event?